# PHP strpos multiple words

Tags: php

Basically I'm trying to see if the following is in a variable called `$restext`.

> [TD="align: left"]'.$num.'[/TD] [TD="align: left"][/TD]

`$num` is a `$_GET` value which is a number.

From what I see it is failing when I use:

```
if(strpos($restext,'[TD="align: left"]'.$num.'[/TD] [TD="align: left"][/TD]')===false) {

}
```

because the string I am searching for is 2 words. There is a space after the first `[/TD]`

How can I search the the variable `$restext` for the string posted above?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please add your code? It is very unclear what you're trying to do at this stage.

Comment: Hi, please see update :) I redid the post.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me, assuming `$num` is the same value in both cases.

Comment: Yes, num is the same but it doesn't work. If I run it, it always says the `to search` was found even if it isn't..

Comment: Provide an example of `restext` where it returns wrong result.

Comment: It always does. Here is an example of it... http://pastebin.com/8T6CL7Un

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you've taken into account the empty cell at the end?

```
$haystack = 'pastebin example';
$num = 1;
$needle = '[TD="align: left"]'.$num.'[/TD] [TD="align: left"][/TD]';
echo strpos($haystack, $needle) === false ? "Not found" : "Found"; //Found
$num = 4;
echo strpos($haystack, $needle) === false ? "Not found" : "Found"; //Not found
```

If you want to replace the value:

```
if(strpos($haystack, $needle) !== false) {
    $haystack = str_replace($needle, "New value", $haystack);
}
```

Comment: Great! It worked!!! Thanks. Let's say I wanted to replace it if it was found how would that work? Like replace this:`[TD="align: left"]'.$num.'[/TD] [TD="align: left"][/TD]`